# @Transactional and inheritance

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, transactions

I used to add `@Transactional` annotations to all Spring services (classes). And then I thought: do I really have to, if the transactional behavior should be the same? (Of course, if it shouldn't, we would add `@Transational` with other parameters to methods.) I tried to find some useful information about inheritance with `@Transactional`, read about `@Inherited` (and it looks like `@Transactional` is `@Inherited`). I experimented with `rollbackFor` and `noRollbackFor` for the following example, and it looks like
`@Transactional` in `GenericService` worked for `doSmthSpecific`.

```
@Transactional
public abstract class GenericService {
    public void doSmthGeneric() {
    }
}

public class SpecificService extends GenericService {
    public void doSmthSpecific() {
    }
}
```

And in case `GenericService` was an interface, I think [it wouldn't work](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5322?focusedCommentId=49133&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-49133). I guess it's more like "correct me if I'm wrong" question, I'd like to know if it's actually all right to add `@Transactional` to superclass only, and if I'm missing something here. A detailed explanation (or a link to such explanation) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

> You can place the @Transactional annotation before an interface definition, a method on an interface, a class definition, or a public method on a class...

They also recommend against annotating interfaces/interface methods.

> Spring recommends that you only annotate concrete classes (and methods of concrete classes) with the @Transactional annotation, as opposed to annotating interfaces. You certainly can place the @Transactional annotation on an interface (or an interface method), but this works only as you would expect it to if you are using interface-based proxies.

Later they go on to explain that it doesn't work when you're using class-based proxies or aspectj weaving.

Comment: Note that if you do use @Transactional on an interface while using a configuration that does not permit it to be used meaningfully, no warning or error will be generated.