# Using Spring transaction proxy between abstract class and child method

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-transactions

I have an abstract base service, and two implementations:

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseService {
  public void mainProcess() {
    for (Foo foo : getFoos()) {
      doSomething(foo);
    }
  }
  abstract List<Foo> getFoos();
  abstract void doSomething(Foo foo);
}

public class ServiceImplOne extends AbstractBaseService {
  protected List<Foo> getFoos() { ... }
  protected void doSomething(Foo foo) { ... }
}

public class ServiceImplTwo extends AbstractBaseService { ... }
```

If something goes wrong in `doSomething(foo)`, I want to rollback any changes made with that object, write the error in a log file, and continue with the next object in the list. So, I'll add a try-catch inside the loop in my base service... and annotate with `@Transactional` the `doSomething` method in the implementation classes. But according to the [Spring's docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations):

> When you use proxies, you should apply the `@Transactional` annotation only to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected, private or package-visible methods with the `@Transactional` annotation, no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the configured transactional settings. If you need to annotate non-public methods, consider using AspectJ (described later).

My methods are `protected`... I could change the visibility to `public`, but there is also the issue that:

> The default advice mode for processing `@Transactional` annotations is `proxy`, which allows for interception of calls through the proxy only. Local calls within the same class cannot get intercepted that way. For a more advanced mode of interception, consider switching to `aspectj` mode in combination with compile-time or load-time weaving.

So, the proxy won't be able to intercept calls from within the same class. **Does that also apply to calls between an abstract class and its implementations**, or will it work as I intend? Is there any easy way to check it myself? (Probably a dumb question, I get a little lost when it comes to Java proxies...)

I've been searching for a while, but I've only managed to find these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762451/transactional-and-inheritance) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736231/does-spring-transaction-work-on-a-concrete-method-of-abstract-class), and they focus on inheritance of the `@Transactional` tag itself... which is not really important in this case, I don't care annotating all the `doSomething` implementations instead of just the abstract method.

Comment: An instance of ServiceImplOne is an instance of AbstractBaseService. There is a single object being created when you create an instance of ServiceImplOne. And its mainProcess() method calls its doSomething() method. The call isn't a call from one Spring bean to another Spring bean, so there's nothing that can be intercepted.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet. I guess it makes sense, I have two classes but only one object... it seems like I have some refactoring to do. Could you please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instance of `ServiceImplOne` is an instance of `AbstractBaseService`. There is a single object being created when you create an instance of `ServiceImplOne`. And its `mainProcess()` method calls its `doSomething()` method.

The call isn't a call from one Spring bean to another Spring bean, so there's nothing that can be intercepted.